# SQL Escape Query String?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I'm unable to escape a query string.
I placed all the variables I will be using for the database into an array;

```
$playerInfo['steamID64'] = $info['steamID64'];
```

And I cannot use it in a query without error messages showing.
Take a look near the end of the query where I try to select and use the variable $playerInfo['steamID64'] below:

```
$query = "SELECT `steamID64` FROM `players` WHERE `steamID64` = '$playerInfo[\'steamID64\']'";
```

It returns the following errors:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/sites/acidicservers.com/public_html/loading-acidic/index.php on line 154
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT \`steamID64\` FROM \`players\` WHERE \`steamID64\` = '{$playerInfo['steamID64']}'";`

Comment: Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Okay I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
$query = "SELECT `steamID64` FROM `players` WHERE `steamID64` = '".$playerInfo['steamID64']."'";
```

Comment: @Acidic, If this answer help, then mark it as answer & as  Jens suggest, better to use prepared statements.